# CMPedometer data more than 7 days

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am trying to collect steps from CMPedometer for 10 days. It works fine for 7 days but returns 0 for last three days.

Here is the code:

```
var days:[String] = []
var stepsTaken:[Int] = []
let activityManager = CMMotionActivityManager()
let pedoMeter = CMPedometer()

var cnt = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getDataForLast10Days()
}

func getDataForLast10Days() {
    if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){
        let serialQueue : DispatchQueue  = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.MyQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM"
        serialQueue.sync(execute: { () -> Void in
            let today = NSDate()
            for day in 1...10{
                let from = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(-7+day) ))
                let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: from as Date)
                let min = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: from as Date)
                let sec = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: from as Date)
                let timeToSub = (hour * 60 + min) * 60 + sec
                let fromDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: (Double(-10+day) * (86400 ) ) - Double(timeToSub))
                let toDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: (Double(-10+day+1) * (86400) ) - Double(timeToSub))
                let dtStr = formatter.string(from: (toDate as Date))

                self.pedoMeter.queryPedometerData(from: fromDate as Date , to: toDate as Date) { (data : CMPedometerData!, error) -> Void in
                    //print("From Date: \(fromDate)","\n\n")
                    if(error == nil){
                        // print(data,"\n\n")
                        print("\(dtStr) : \(data.numberOfSteps)")
                        self.days.append(dtStr)
                        self.stepsTaken.append(Int(data.numberOfSteps))
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

But as the days increase since I have created the app, data increases for one day everyday. It's been 2 days since I created the app. It has data for 9 days and so on. How do I tackle this?

Please let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is alright.

According to the method definition for the instance method `queryPedometerData(from:to:withHandler:)`

> Only the past seven days worth of data is stored and available for you
>   to retrieve. Specifying a start date that is more than seven days in
>   the past returns only the available data.

[See Apple's Documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmpedometer/1613946-querypedometerdata)

Comment: Are there any other sources of user activity data? We can fetch workouts from HealthKit, but its not quite what CoreMotion provides...